# Eclipse Jar Build Path

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I have looked over articles and forum posts about this; making a lib and adding it to your build path. Well, I did this exactly. I have a libs folder and from that, I tried to ways. I selected them, right clicked, went to build path, and added them. It moved them to a library. I also tried to right click the project, go to properties, go to build path, libraries, add jar, and selected it from my libs folder. However, when I run it, it still doesn't find the jar, what did I do wrong here?

Step 1:
Select Jar Files in Lib Folder > Right Click > Build Path > Add

Step 2:
Select Project > Right Click > Properties > Build Path > Libraries > Add Jars > Select and add the jars.

Comment: What is the type of your eclipse project: Java Project, Dynamic Web Project? Can you provide some screenshots about the lib folder with jars and Java Build Path view?

Comment: http://imgur.com/goEVTn5

Comment: It's also a JavaProject, and the build path view: http://imgur.com/CR3zbsH - Also, I was changing some stuff to try and find a solution, so the two images don't match on the Joda-Time, they are two different jars, but they do match in the project. Right now, I have the normal one on.

Answer (score 0):

If the JAR files are showing up under Referenced Libraries, then Eclipse should be including them in the build path. I would make sure that 1) the JAR file has the file you think it does in it, and 2) that the JAR doesn't have any native libraries that you need (which would prevent it from working).

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/installation.html - So on the bottom of that page, it says that I need Apache Ant or Maven to build from source. That doesn't apply to this situation, correct?

Comment: I found out that this works when doing an executable, but I am doing just a jar. Is it possible to do this with just jars?

Comment: A JAR isn't building from source, it's including a pre-built library. :D What do you mean that it works when doing an executable?

Comment: Whenever I make an executable jar file and then run it, it works with a libs folder and all that. That's what I meant.

Comment: So Eclipse is telling you that it can't find joda-time classes in your files, and it won't run them correctly, but if you export as an executable JAR file, it runs fine?

Answer (score 0):

try to right click the project, go to properties, go to build path.

them remove the existing JRE System library

finaly add new lybrary, JRE System library